# Adding font-awesome icon in wordpress menu

Tags: css, menu, font-awesome

I am new.I want to to know Font-aewsome Icon adding process in Wordpress menu.I have install font-awesome in my theme.Just want to know process how to add this in Dynamic menu?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the menu item, if you open the link, there will be CSS Classes. you can put css class of font-awesome. 
   For example type it in input box of css classes.

```
 fa-user
```

It appears on the side of menu link

Comment: If you cannot find "CSS Classes" field go to "Screent Options" (on the top right of "Appearance > Menus") and under "Show advanced" menu properties, check "CSS Classes". http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item